# mySQLI запросы через функцию

Tags: php

Делаю запрос, получаю ошибку:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysql in /var/www/... on line 58
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in /var/www/... on line 58
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /var/www/... on line 63
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: mysql in /var/www/... on line 58
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in /var/www/... on line 58
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /var/www/... on line 66

```
$mysql = mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpwd,$dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($mysql, "utf8");

$queries_num = 0;

function db_query($sql)
{
    global $queries_num;
    $queries_num++;
    return mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);
}

$var = db_query("SELECT * FROM ".prefix."main");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($var);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае переменная `$mysql` является глобальной и из функции `db_query` она не видна.

Проблема решается либо использованием оператора `global`, либо передачей этой переменной как еще одного аргумента функции.

Чтобы не попадать в такие ситуации в будущем - рекомендую прочитать следующий [раздел документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)